# Recursive function to traverse directories using fork() running too many times

Tags: c, recursion, directory

I am trying to get a better understanding of the concept of forking a process by traversing a directory in C.

My function is not working how I expect it to: some of my directories and files are being visited multiple times.

I'm supposed to start at the current working directory and list all files/folders.  Every time a subdirectory is found, I'm supposed to call fork() and do the same, until I've exhausted every file/directory.  I don't need to visit the items in any specific order, but I do need to visit each one exactly once.

I got the program working recursively without using fork().  But I can't quite get it right using fork().  Here's the function.  It just gets passed the string ".", to start it off at the current working directory.

```
int traverse(char* directory)
{
    struct dirent *currentDir;  
    DIR *traverser = opendir(directory);

    if (traverser == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open directory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((currentDir = readdir(traverser)) != NULL)
    {       
        if (currentDir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            int PID = fork();
            forkCount++;

            char pathBuffer[1024];

            if (PID == 0)
            {
                snprintf(pathBuffer, sizeof(pathBuffer), "%s/%s", directory, currentDir->d_name);
                traverse(pathBuffer);
            }
            else
            {
                listOfPIDS[forkCount] = PID;
                int status = 0;
                wait(&status);
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", currentDir->d_name);
        }
    }

    closedir(traverser);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After the `if (PID == 0)` the child will call `traverse` and when `traverse` returns the child will continue the `while` loop. The parent also will continue the `while` loop after waiting for the child. So I expect the first subdirectory will be visited once, the second subdirectory will be visited twice, and so on.

Comment: Thank you!  Your observation helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking the other user's comment into consideration and playing around some more, I came up with this solution.  By breaking the `while()` loop after a child process calls the function recursively, the same folders/files are not revisited.  As the other user pointed out in their comment, when the parent calls fork and begins waiting, the child begins and calls the function again recursively.  Once the child's recursive call is done, it returns to the exact same spot in the directory and begins listing all the files.  Once that finishes, the parent is done waiting, and returns to the exact same spot and begins listing the files.  So both the parent and child were returning to the same spot in the directory and listing files.  Simply adding `exit(0);` after the child's recursive call finished executing solved the problem. Also, I moved `pathBuffer[]` and `forkCount++` into the section for the child processes, because the parent doesn't need to worry about that.

Here's the code:

```
int traverse(char* directory)
{
    struct dirent *currentDir;  
    DIR *traverser = opendir(directory);

    if (traverser == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open directory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((currentDir = readdir(traverser)) != NULL)
    {       
        if (currentDir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            int PID = fork();

            if (PID == 0)
            {
                forkCount++;        
                char pathBuffer[1024];
                snprintf(pathBuffer, sizeof(pathBuffer), "%s/%s", directory, currentDir->d_name);
                traverse(pathBuffer);
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                listOfPIDS[forkCount] = PID;
                int status = 0;
                wait(&status); //wait at end
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            printf("%s: Proc'd by %d\n", currentDir->d_name, getpid());
        }
    }

    closedir(traverser);
    return 0;
}
```